# I'm having issues with my Terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm having some issues trying to open up Atom in my terminal. I know I can open it manually but I'm trying to figure out what exactly is the issue.

This is what I'm getting when I try to open Atom in my Terminal.

`Cannot locate Atom.app, it is usually located in /Applications. Set the ATOM_PATH environment variable to the directory containing Atom.app.`

Anyone have an idea as to what the issue is???

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is, and **exactly** what to do to solve it. What part of that isn't clear? The issue is that your system **cannot locate Atom.app**, and to fix it you should **Set the ATOM_PATH environment variable to the directory containing Atom.app**. It even tells you where the usual location is to find Atom.app (in  `/Applications`. Does having it repeated help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets get this fixed for you.

The error you're getting is indicating Atom isn't located where it should be, which is the Applications folder. Open up Applications and confirm it isn't there. If it isn't, locate where Atom is on your computer and drag it into the Applications folder. If you have Atom and Terminal both open, restart them. Then try opening Atom from the Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If your application is called "Atom 2" or something, try this:

1. Open `/usr/local/bin/atom`
2. Change the line `ATOM_APP_NAME=Atom.app` to something like `ATOM_APP_NAME='Atom 2.app'`

Comment: Had the same problem and this worked perfectly for me ! , thanks